# CompletableFuture.allOf() vs anyOf()

Tags: java, javadoc, completable-future

From the javadocs,

```
AllOf()
```

> If **any of the given** CompletableFutures complete exceptionally, then
>   the returned CompletableFuture also does so, with a
>   CompletionException holding this exception as its cause.

```
AnyOf()
```

> if it completed exceptionally, the returned CompletableFuture also
>   does so, with a CompletionException holding this exception as its
>   cause.

Does this mean both allOf() and anyOf() behaves in the same way when any of the CompletableFuture throws Exception?

The question is with the phrase

> **returned CompletableFuture also does so**

appearing in both the methods without explicitly mentioning when if exception occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. `anyOf` gives the result of any one of the futures to complete, whether exceptionally or not. `allOf` does not complete until all passed futures are complete, including exceptionally completed futures. If any futures completed exceptionally, the first exception is reflected in the result.

Basically, an exception from `anyOf` will always come from the one future that completed, whereas with `allOf` it may come from any.